# jquery :even :odd not working as expected IE10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

On a page with a table,

In $(document).ready(), I have the following code:

```
   populateTable();  // creates and appends TR's to the table from in-memory vars
   $("#table1Body tr:even").css("background-color", "rgb(181,221,181)");
   $("#table1Body tr:odd").css("background-color", "rgb(255,255,220)");
```

This works as expected in Firefox, Chrome and Safari but...

In IE10 only a few (sometimes none) of the table rows are alternately colored
UNTIL I move the mouse into the table on screen and out again, then in again.
The first time I move the mouse into the table some of the rows gain the correct
background color but some don't.  When I move the mouse out and back in again all the
rows get the correct background.

The populateTable function doesn't do any ajax or anything else that might cause a problem related to anynchronous completion, it simply loads in-memory variables into 's and appends them to .  To verify this, I bundled the code into a function and executed the function from a setTimeout with a 5 second delay - this didn't change a thing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You are missing a closing paren on your first `rgb` call. Is that a typo in your code, or just your example.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.9.1.  Same thing happens using jquery 1.8.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `:nth-child()` pseudo selector.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgb(181,221,181);
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,220);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sn6R5/

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child

So your jQuery selector would be something like:

```
$("#table1Body tr:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "rgb(181,221,181)");
```

Comment: This is a styling thing, it should be done in the CSS like you list in your example.

Comment: I put the nth-child css in - worked well for IE but not for Firefox.  At this point I have the nth-child css in addition to the jquery even/odd and that combination seems to work for all browsers so far

Comment: @RoyHB That's odd, when I look at my fiddle in Firefox it works fine. Assume your version of FF is up to date?

Comment: My mistake, fat thumbs had commented the wrong line, works in all browsers I test against (IE8,9,10 FF20, Chrome 26 and Safari).  Thanks for the tip about nth-child.  I knew about it but for some reason I had avoided it because I had this idea there were significant cross-browser issues.

Comment: @RoyHB. Good stuff. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a parenthesis on your first `rgb()` line.

Try this.

```
populateTable();  // creates and appends TR's to the table from in-memory vars
$("#table1Body tr:even").css("background-color", "rgb(181,221,181)");
$("#table1Body tr:odd").css("background-color", "rgb(255,255,220)");
```

IE isn't the greatest at detecting these kind of human mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the missing paren but that didn't elminate the problem.  Behaviour unchanged.  I've fixed the code in the question too.